# Copies of $\ell_\infty^k$ in subspaces of the space of operators between $n$-dimensional Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, operator-theory

> Are there a positive integer $k$ and an unbounded increasing function $d:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ (of growth order $\Omega(n^2)$) such that for any $n$-dimensional Banach spaces $X,Y$, the Banach space $L(X,Y)$ of linear operators from $X$ to $Y$ contains a linear subspace $Z\subset L(X,Y)$ of dimension $d(n)$ such that $Z$ contains no 2-isomorphic copy of the Banach space $\ell_\infty^k$?

**Remark 1.** This is never true for $Z=L(X,Y)$.

**Remark 2.** A positive solution will solve the dichotomy problem of Pisier (see Question 6 in this survey [paper](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~naor/homepage%20files/ICM2018.pdf) of Naor).

The problem was posed on 28.06.2019 by Gideon Schechtman (Israel) on page [136](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=2&page=136) of [Volume 2](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php).

Comment: Re: Remark 1. I see that  $d(n) =  \log n$ is immediate from Dvoretzky's Theorem, but is something better known?

Comment: What is known if $d(n)$ grows more slowly?